# How can I get the discriminator of an instruction in an Anchor Solana IDL?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, anchor-program-idl

First of all can someone explain to me what a discriminator is, in the context of Solana instructions, in simple terms?

Second, how can I get the discriminator of an instruction in an Anchor Solana IDL?

both of these Solana programs https://solscan.io/account/1349iiGjWC7ZTbu6otFmJwztms122jEEnShKgpVnNewy#anchorProgramIDL and
https://solscan.io/account/7h7uYbDBZkiTvWLmMsWNAEs2VVNqfV56uSfP9hbjJMP8#anchorProgramIDL

have the same instruction name "completeWithdraw".

I have seen posts where they said to take the 8 first bytes of the "global:completeWithdraw", but wouldn't that mean they would have the same discriminator?

I have found in non-anchor IDLs, the discriminator is defined as part of the instruction object.
https://github.com/pyth-network/pyth-client/blob/idl/program/idl.json

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark this as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

> First of all can someone explain to me what a discriminator is, in the context of Solana instructions, in simple terms?

[What is Anchor (8 bytes) discriminator](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/what-is-anchor-8-bytes-discriminator)

> Second, how can I get the discriminator of an instruction in an Anchor Solana IDL?

```
pub fn sighash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);

    let mut sighash = [0u8; 8];
    sighash.copy_from_slice(
        &anchor_client::anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()
            [..8],
    );
    sighash
}

println!("{:?}", sighash("global", "initialize"));
```

You can use this function to get the discriminator for your instructions. You only need to pass the instruction names.

Comment: absolute life saver. tysm