# Is there a way to get size_of an account from the client?

Tags: account

I'd like to use `getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption`. With that said, it expects a parameter of the size of the data account. I'd like to know if there's a way to get the estimate size of an account or whether I have to calculate it by hand.

In my rust code, I use `use std::mem::size_of` to get the size of a struct. Anything similar in the client side which is the one setting the rent budget or maybe something similar in the IDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
const program = anchor.workspace.MyProgram as Program<MyProgram>;
const myAccountSize = program.account.myAccount.size;
console.log('Size', myAccountSize);
```

Note that `size` also includes the [anchor discriminator](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/what-is-anchor-8-bytes-discriminator), so it will be 8 bytes bigger than you might expect.

Comment: If you are allocating space for the rent-free exception, you do have to include those 8 bytes, so it would be appropriate to use directly for OP's purposes.

Comment: Absolutely - I included this just as an FYI, as otherwise it might come as a surprise that an account holding e.g. a u32 would return 12 with `.size` instead  of the more intuitive 4